# printing boolean

Tags: php, boolean

Thank you for dropping by.

Code

```
$variable = 10;
$variableOne = 10;

$result = $variable == $variableOne;
echo $result;
```

When comparison between $variable and $variableOne returns false, Why is $result not assigned 0? However the end result is otherwise and $result is assigned 1 when comparison returns true.

Thank you for your time,
PHP Beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$result` is assigned `true` or `false`. That's important. It's not `1` or `0`, it's `true` or `false`. When `echo`ing `true`, it is output as `1`. When `echo`ing `false`, it is output as an empty string. Try `var_dump($result)` instead to see the difference.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting

Comment: Using var_dump( $result ); outputs bool(false). but what if i wanted to use $result in an if statement

Comment: @user832596: then just use it in `if` statement: `if ($result) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: @user No, sorry. I can't recommend the online documentation highly enough though.

Answer (score 0):

Perform `var_dump($result);` and see that this variable is boolean, because it has been assigned with `==` operator evaluation which is *always boolean*.

Comment: @user832596: unfortunately I don't know any good modern books for beginners, sorry :-(

Comment: @DonutsAndCode, I would recommend Beginning PHP 5.3 by Matt Doyle (The guy behind elated.com). It definitely taught me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

$result is not the result of an expression but in your code is a (invalid) assignment.

Syntax should be like this:

```
if($variable == $variableOne){
    $result = true;
} else {
    $result = false;
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: Lolwhut? You're **completely wrong**. `$result` **is** a result of expression evaluation. And in his code it is **valid** assignment.